# Building zxing's cpp/lib Fails under Fedora14 even when Following instructions Exactly

Tags: python, build, scons, zxing

That is, following the instructions in zxing/cpp/README, which say 'To build the library only:
- Run "scons lib" in this folder (cpp)'

Well, that is exactly what I did. But I get:

```
 scons lib
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
o build/core/src/zxing/BarcodeFormat.o -c -O0 -g3 -ggdb -Wall -Ibuild/core/src build/core/src/zxing/BarcodeFormat.cpp
sh: o: command not found
```

Withs this "O: command not found" repeated many times.

I thought the problem might be gcc not found, so I checked for that: it is installed. I took only a brief look at the python of scons before I gave up on trying to figure ouw why it is looking for a command 'o'. Of course there is none.

BTW: I got my copy of zxing 1.7 using wget only three days ago and the yum installation of 'scons' today. So they are up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are correct, and that SCons isn't finding GCC. Your best bet is to add a call to display the contents of some (or all) of the environment. As shown below, you can either pull out specific variable, or [show the whole environment](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x4743.html). The best place would probably near a call to the builder (SharedLibrary, StaticLibrary or Program). For an environment named 'env':

```
print env.Dump()
print env['CC']
print env['CXX']
```

Ensuring that an appropriate default environment is being used initially (probably something like):

```
env = DefaultEnvironment( ... )
```

Or that the environment variables on your system (including path) are being propagated through to SCons. One way to do this is by:

```
import os
# ...
env = Environment( ENV = os.environ, ... )
```

In extreme cases you can resolve this problem by providing an explicit path to the compiler:

```
env['CC'] = '/usr/bin/gcc'
```

**Edit:**

These changes need to be made in  an appropriate SConstruct or SConscript file. Which depends on the exact project, and what you're trying to achieve - in the case of the current version of zxing on google code, it would be reasonable to make the changes on or near line 40 of the [SConscript file](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/cpp/SConscript#40)

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I tried following the instructions at the link you gave titled "show the whole environment", I got the following error: File "/usr/bin/scons", line 73, in <module>
    newenv = Environment()NameError: name 'Environment' is not defined I apologize for the bad formatting here, I can't figure out why Stack Overflow insists on interpreting Newline as "Save Edits" instead of allowing me to insert. BTW: I was surprised to see that no 'env' is even defined in scons. What is up with that? So I could have used that name instead of 'myenv' and got the same error.

Comment: @Matt - with respect to the environments, zxing uses a SCons trick in the SConstruct to make sure that all compiled files (.o, .os and .so files) will end up in an appropriate 'build' directory. The result is that most of the environment setup is moved into the SConscript file.

Comment: @Matt - with respect to the Stack Overflow comment newline formatting, in cases where there are non-trivial modifications or extensions to the question, normal best practice is to edit your question, and post a 'check what changed comment' where it's required. This has the advantage of letting you use the question formatting/editing tools rather than the comment ones.

Comment: Hi, Andrew. I made the change to get env and Dump it at line 40 in SConscript as you suggested. CC looks reasonable, 'gcc', so do CCCOM and CCSUFFIXES. But CXX is not defined. and CFLAGS is '[]', CXXFILESUFFIXES is '.cxx' only. None of these look right to me: could this be the problem?

Comment: Progress! Yes, it looks like the path variable isn't correct, so I'd try the third option (ENV=os.environ) in the SConscript on line 6.